# Border-radius gone crazy after crop image from bigger picture by IMAGICK

Tags: imagick

I used Imagick to handle all the operations.

```
$finalWHRatio = $finalW/$finalH;
    $im = new \imagick($srcFilePath);
    $im -> setResolution(300, 300);
    $im -> setImageFormat('gif');

    $this->autoRotateImage($im);

    $geo = $im->getImageGeometry();
    $srcImgWidth = $geo['width'];
    $srcImgHeight = $geo['height'];
    $srcWHRatio = $srcImgWidth/$srcImgHeight;

    $resizedH = '';
    $redizedW = '';
    if($srcWHRatio > $finalWHRatio){
        $resizedH = $finalH;
        $resizedW = $srcWHRatio*$finalH;

        $im -> resizeImage($resizedW, $resizedH, \Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);

        $x_crop = $resizedW/2 - ($finalW/2);
        $y_crop = 0;
        $im -> cropImage($finalW, $finalH, $x_crop, $y_crop);
    }else{
        $resizedW = $finalH;
        $resizedH = $finalW/$srcWHRatio;

        $im -> resizeImage($resizedW, $resizedH, \Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);

        $x_crop = 0;
        $y_crop = $resizedH/2 - ($finalH/2);
        $im -> cropImage($finalW, $finalH, $x_crop, $y_crop);
    }
```

Now after cropping and resizing I have - 120x120 px image. But  when presented on profile page, if cropped from Portrait appears like this

[image: img]

If image is landscape the image border distortion is horizontal.

Is there some other informations encoded into image that should i change? Or its a problem with css?

Answer (score 0):

I used $im -> setImagePage($finalW, $finalH, 0, 0); And now it's working fine